# OBSOLETE - Stacklipse - Eclipse plugin preview

Tags: app, obsolete, java

> ### Obsolete. This plugin is for/uses a decommissioned version of the API.

### About

Stacklipse is an eclipse plugin that utilizes Stack Apps API to provide a search view in Eclipse. Currently just provide a prototype preview.

### Screenshot

[image: screen]

#### License

EPL

#### Download

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/stacklipse/downloads/list

#### Install

Just copy the stacklipse_1.0.0.201007111306.jar into your eclipse dropin folder.

#### Platform

Java 6, Eclipse 3.5+
Should works on most platforms, but just tested in win7.

### Contact

chenyuejie@gmail.com

### Code

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/stacklipse/

code will be uploaded when beta is released.

### Libraries used

- carson's StackExchange Java client library
- freemarker

Comment: Looks good! Please consider listing this on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com).

Comment: I have played around with the Eclipse Communication Framework (ECF) a few months ago, and built a simple prototype, which integrates with StackExchange sites and provides a simple view with user gravatar, reputation and favourite questions. See the code at https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/se4ecf/

Comment: Have you considered integrating with http://eclipse.org/mylyn ? Seems like a nice fit.

Comment: @NathanOsman Is there a place where I can share [my plugin](https://github.com/MarounMaroun/SO-Eclipse-Plugin) in Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MarounMaroun what do you mean?

Comment: @NathanOsman I mean is there a stack exchange website where we can share helpful software with others?

Comment: @MarounMaroun if it relates to the public API, then it should be shared here. Otherwise, no, there isn't anywhere.